# reason for adding console consumer in deny list in burrow configuration

Tags: apache-kafka, aws-msk, kafka-burrow

I recently started using burrow and for burrow configuration, I see below configuration for group-deny list at lots of places including AWS MSK documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/consumer-lag.html
But I cannot find any possible documentation around the same. Can someone help me to understand why below config is added/required ?

group-denylist="^(console-consumer-|python-kafka-consumer-|quick-).*$"

group-allowlist=""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with MSK.

The console consumer generates random group ids, so there's no good reason for Burrow to look at those. The others are likely the same, but the documentation is probably just pointing out that the property is a regex

If you needed to track lag of `kafka-console-consumer`, then manually add `--group` with a different value